# Remove leading apostrophe and apply text format to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove the leading apostrophe from the cells and want the cells to be in text format via macro.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Long
With Range("B1:B999").CurrentRegion
    .Replace What:="'", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
End With
Range("B1:B999").NumberFormat = "@"

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary test in title

Comment: The leading apostrophe is neither contained in `.Value` nor `.Value2` nor `.Text` of a `Range`, so you can't simply `.Replace` it.  You can recognise it via `.PrefixCharacter = "'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("NAME HERE")
Dim rng as range
Dim strInput as string, strOutput as string

For each rng in ws.columns(2).rows("1:999")
    strInput = ws.Columns(2).Rows(rng.Row)
    strOutput= Replace(strInput , "'", "")
    ws.Columns(2).Rows(rng.Row) = strOutput
Next rng
```

Comment: Thank you very much,i really appreciate your help but After running the above code i am getting he error like:- run-time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method.